# How to sort data in GridView in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, gridview

How to sort datatable obtained by GridView according to some column.
I am trying to do something like this but it is not working.

```
protected void GridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType() != typeof(GridView))
        return;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)((GridView)sender).DataSource;

    DataTable dtClone = dt.Clone();


    dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(row => row.Field <string>(e.SortExpression));
    ((GridView)sender).Source(dtClone);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either re-bind the gridview to the sorted datatable, or you can apply the sort expression to the gridview itself rather than the underlying bound table.

This is a pretty good summary with links to examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add the attributes  `OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" AllowSorting="true"` in Gridview

and `SortExpression="ColumnName"` in the column

and implement OnSorting Event.

check the links

[Sorting the GridView's Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)

[How to sort the data in grid view?](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/162501-How-sort-data-grid-view.aspx)

[How to sort data into GridView](http://forums.asp.net/t/1206311.aspx)

[Sorting Data in a GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875.aspx)

[How to sort GridView?](http://www.netomatix.com/development/GridViewSorting.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this in the past to sort a DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // your data table
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "your_field" + "sort_direction";
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = ("your_field" + "sort_direction");
yourGridView.DataSource = dv;
```

Answer (score 1):

When sorting, make sure to cast your table to a DataView.  You'll save yourself a lot of time over manually implementing sorting methods.